# No sound from html5 video streams in WinForms app with WebBrowser control

Tags: winforms, video-streaming, webbrowser-control

I just did a simple WinForms app in Visual Studio 2017. On the main Form1 I put WebBrowser control. On Form1  load I navigate to vimeo.com page

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("http://vimeo.com/"));
    }
```

Any video which I open plays without sound. How can I enable sound to play in app?

Comment: If what you shared in *EDIT* is the answer of your question, remove it from the question and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that problem is in Internet Explorer's multimedia option "Play background sound" that is turned off on my PC. My particular problem could be solved by two ways:

1. Manual: Internet Explorer-> Internet Options-> Advanced-> Play sounds in webpages under Multimedia set to "on".
2. Programmatically:

   ```
           RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main", true);
           key.SetValue("Play_Background_Sounds", "yes", RegistryValueKind.String);
   ```